# InDesign CS5 Script: How can I automate "Alt + click" on the XML structure pane?

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have this script, which is displaying the  `View --> Show Structure`  pane:

```
with(obj.doc.xmlViewPreferences)
{
    // this opens the View --> Show Structure pane
    showStructure = true;

    showTagMarkers = true;
    showTaggedFrames = true;
    showTextSnippets = true;
}
```

However, the root node remains minimized. I found that holding the  `Alt`  key and clicking on this root node *will* expand the entire tree though.

So is there a way to programmatically execute "Alt + click" on this root node? **I am using Windows, and CS5.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get close by selecting nodes. E.g. to select all elements at the 3rd level and on the way expanding all on the levels above you would use

```
app.select(
    app.activeDocument.xmlElements.item(0) // the root element
    .xmlElements.everyItem() // repeat this line for each nesting level
    .xmlElements.everyItem() // and so forth
    .getElements() // provide an array with the actual selectable items
);
```

Repeat for the indicated line for deeper levels. With the following snippet you could also select XML attributes of those elements without children:

```
.xmlAttributes.everyItem()
```

Finally deselect to clean up the selection highlights.

```
app.select(null);
```

Edit: For an arbitrary depth you can use a loop. It just should ensure there are elements in the XMLElement / XMLAttribute collections before asking for them. The resulting code:

```
var items = app.activeDocument.xmlElements.everyItem();
while( items.xmlElements.length ) {
    items = items.xmlElements.everyItem();
    app.select(items.getElements());
    if( items.xmlAttributes.length )
        app.select(items.xmlAttributes.everyItem().getElements());
}
app.select(null);
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for the help @user1589939! Is there a way to determine the max number of xml layers? I noticed it does not execute when you go beyond the number of layers that the XML actually has...